# ¿Como crear directorios y almacenar fotografias en android 10?

Tags: java, android, almacenamiento

Ya tenía anteriormente un proyecto en el que tomaba una fotografía y era almacenada en una carpeta del dispositivo.

Hoy recibo notificaciones que la creación no deja tomar fotografías y esto pasa porque no encuentra la carpeta y por ende no inicia la camara.

Descubrí que solo no funciona con dispositivos que tienen android 10

```
    private void capturarFotografía() {
    // Objeto de tipo File, le paso la ruta y el nombre del directorio "Evidencia/Fotografias"
    miFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DIRECTORIO_IMAGEN);
    Log.i("Carpeta", "tomarEvidencia: " + miFile); // Para verificar la ruta

    boolean isCreada = miFile.exists(); // Verifico que exista la carpeta

    if (!isCreada) { // Si no esta creada intenta crear la carpeta
        try {
            isCreada = miFile.mkdirs(); // Uso el metodo mkdirs()
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("CREACION CARPETA:", "NO SE CREO POR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
if(isCreada){
 // ... demas codigo que toma la foto, nombra y almacena pero no avanza pues la carpeta no se crea
}
```

- Ya verifique el almacenamiento, y aunque se ejecuta mkdirs() no crea el directorio.
- Solo pasa con versiones 10
- Ya intente primero usar .mkdirs() sin el if, cuando inicie la app no la generaba, solo metiendola en el if la creaba.
- No arroja error alguno, todo lo contrario dice que si la crea pero reviso y nada.
- Si tiene permisos y demas, como dije funcionaba hasta ahora que intentan usar en dispositivos con android 10, incluso en el emulador.

Honestamente no se que pase, jaja :( ojala alguien sepa y pueda orientar al respecto gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()), el método `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` dice lo siguiente:

> Este método fue desaprobado en el nivel 29 de API.
> Para mejorar la privacidad del usuario, el acceso directo a dispositivos de almacenamiento externo / compartido está en desuso. Cuando una aplicación se dirige a Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, la ruta devuelta por este método ya no es directamente accesible para las aplicaciones. Las aplicaciones pueden continuar accediendo al contenido almacenado en el almacenamiento compartido / externo migrando a alternativas como Context # getExternalFilesDir (String), MediaStore o Intent # ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Una manera de solucionarlo, es agregarle `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` en tu `<application>`, pero no es lo recomendable, esto solo habilitará que el código que estas utilizando funcione, pero según android deberías trabajarlo de otra manera.

Puedes utilizar el método `getExternalFilesDir()` del objeto `Context`. Pero recuerda que cuando desinstales tu app también se eliminaran los objetos que guardaste.

Finalmente, puedes utilizar [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) que es lo que recomienda la documentación para trabajar con media files.

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias!